# Python - CSV to dict - unicode characters in keys

Tags: python

I implemented the follwoing csv to dict method:

```
def csv_to_dict(path):
    res = {}
    with open(path, newline='') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            for key, value in row.items():
                if key in res:
                    res[key].append(value)
                else:
                    res[key] = [value]

    return res
```

This methods works as desired, except an issue 
If I take the following input `.csv`

```
Lfd. Nr.,Parameter 1,Parameter 2
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

The output of the above function is on MAc OS:

```
{'\ufeffLfd. Nr.': ['1', '1'], 'Parameter 1': ['2','2'], 'Parameter 2' : ...
```

On Windows I get the following output:

```
{"u00efu00bbu00bfLfd. Nr.": ['1', '1'], 'Parameter 1': ['2','2'], 'Parameter 2' : ...
```

How to get rid off these characters in the first key? Why are these there?

Desired output:

```
{'Lfd. Nr.': ['1', '1'], 'Parameter 1': ['2','2'], 'Parameter 2' : ...
```

---

**UPDATE**
my csv file is encoded in utf-8.

I also tried (without success):

```
with open(path, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
```

---

**Solution** based on marked link to SO question:

```
with open(path,"r", newline='',encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file
```

Comment: The `utf-8` encoding does not skip the byte order mark. See the dupe for the encoding that will. Then proceed to hate Microsoft for trying to mainstream the bastardized version of UTF-8 that includes a byte order mark.

Answer (score -1):

In place of **key** variable write **str(key)** as it is used in res[key] inside inner loop of the function

Comment: I'm getting an error im my IDE: unresolved reference. Is it suited for python 3? Do I have to import something?

Comment: Its is for upto python 2.7 use str(key, 'utf-8') instead for python 3.x

Comment: It says at each place: `TypeError: decoding str is not supported`

Comment: My Bad. In Python3 a str is unicode, ie. it is "decoded" so use str(key)

Comment: This is wrong. See the dupe target.